# How to plot a intersection operation on two vectors MatLab

Tags: matlab, vector

I'm trying to represent a the intersection of two fuzzy sets as a 3d mesh in MatLab.

Here are my sets of vectors:

```
x = [0.3 0.5 0.7]
y = [0.5 0.7 0.1]
```

Followed by these statements:

```
[u,v] = meshgrid(x,y)
w = min(u,v)
mesh(u,v,w)
```

The `x` and `y` ticks seem to be all over the place and do not correlate to the actual index number of each vector i.e. `1 to 3`, and the graph should represent the shape of a small triangle/T-norm.

At the moment it looks like this:

[image: Graph]

Here is an example out of my book I'm following:

[image: fuzzy sets]

Ignore what looks like fractions, they are delimiters.  Here is the resulting graph:

[image: fuzzy intersection]

Comment: Posted an answer. Is that what you expected? If not, you need to explain more carefully what you are trying to achieve. Not everybody knows what a fuzzy intersection is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, its not quite what I'm looking for so what I will do is edit my initial post with two vectors/sets and a graph of what it should look like.

Comment: Sorry, a fuzzy intersection is the logical AND of two fuzzy sets.  We take the minimum of both sets in this case to produce a new set.  So the example image is a 3 dimensional illustration of sets `f` and `d` being intersected.  I'm just trying to figure out how to graph an example myself.

Comment: I think I figured it out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking up fuzzy sets and intersections, here's what I've come up with. First, let's reproduce the textbook example:

```
% possible values and associated degrees of truth for F
Fv = 1 : 5;
Ft = [0 0.5 1 0.5 0];

% possible values and associated degrees of truth for D
Dv = 2 : 4;
Dt = [0 1 0];

% determine degrees of truth for fuzzy intersection
It = bsxfun(@min, Ft', Dt);

% plot
h = mesh(Dv, Fv, It);
set(h, 'FaceColor', 'none')
set(h, 'EdgeColor', 'k')
xlim([0 4.5])
ylim([0 5])
xlabel D
ylabel F
view(37.5, 30)
```

The result is:

[image: fuzzy intersection]

Not as pretty as in your book, but the same thing.

Applying the same code to your example yields:

[image: fuzzy intersection]

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Maybe the graph in the book was physically drawn.

Comment: You're welcome. :) Yes, or at least not as a simple 3d-plot. The authors thought about how it should look like and connected the vertices of the pyramidal shape.

Answer (score 1):

Via the arguments `u,v` you are telling mesh to use the values in them, i.e. the values from `x` and `y`, for the positioning of the data points and corresponding ticks. If you just want positions and ticks at 1, 2, 3, leave these arguments out.

```
mesh(w)
```

[image]

Comment: It turns out that this actually is the correct plot, as should become more clear from my second answer.